# Using Textview.setText() with parseobjects

Tags: android, parse-platform, textview, settext

So I'm trying to add text from a parseobject to a TextView using the setText function.
I have converted what I want to add to strings but the program keeps crashing and I have not found anyone else with this problem so I figured I would post is here.

Anyways here is the code in question:

```
String text = (String)object.get("Text");
            Log.d("Recept", "text: " + text);
            int time = (int)object.get("Time");
            Log.d("Recept", "time: " + time);
            ParseFile image = (ParseFile)object.get("Picture");

            TextView recipeText = (TextView) findViewById(R.id.recipeText);
            recipeText.setText(text);

            TextView recipeTime = (TextView) findViewById(R.id.recipeTime);
            recipeTime.setText(time);

            Log.d("Recept", "The text was fine");

            ParseImageView recipeImage = (ParseImageView) findViewById(R.id.recipeImage);
            recipeImage.setParseFile(image);
```

The log logs everything upt o "the text was fine" and returns the strings I want to add so I know that there isn't anything fishy with the code before that.

I'll add the part before this under here just in case though:

```
public class RecipePage extends AppCompatActivity{

//ListView lv;
/**
 * ATTENTION: This was auto-generated to implement the App Indexing API.
 * See https://g.co/AppIndexing/AndroidStudio for more information.
 */
private GoogleApiClient client;

@Override
protected void onCreate(Bundle savedInstanceState) {

    //ParseQueryAdapter<ParseObject> mainAdapter;

    Log.d("Recept", "Recipe on it's way!");
    super.onCreate(savedInstanceState);
    setContentView(R.layout.recipe_page);
    Log.d("Recept", "I made it in!");


    //int key2 = 2;
    String key = getIntent().getStringExtra("key");
    String label = getIntent().getStringExtra("Title");
    Log.d("Recept", "The found key was: " + key);
    //lv = (ListView) findViewById(R.id.listView2);
    setTitle(label);

    //Begin search
    ParseQuery<ParseObject> query = ParseQuery.getQuery("Recept");
    query.getInBackground(key, new GetCallback<ParseObject>() {
        public void done(ParseObject object, ParseException e) {
            Log.d("Recept", "I got this far");
            if (e == null) {
                Log.d("Recept", "I'm happy!");
            } else {
                Log.d("Recept", "Error, something went wrong: " + e);
            }
            String text = (String)object.get("Text");
            Log.d("Recept", "text: " + text);
            int time = (int)object.get("Time");
            Log.d("Recept", "time: " + time);
            ParseFile image = (ParseFile)object.get("Picture");

            TextView recipeText = (TextView) findViewById(R.id.recipeText);
            recipeText.setText(text);

            TextView recipeTime = (TextView) findViewById(R.id.recipeTime);
            recipeTime.setText(time);

            Log.d("Recept", "The text was fine");

            ParseImageView recipeImage = (ParseImageView) findViewById(R.id.recipeImage);
            recipeImage.setParseFile(image);
        }
    });
```

Sorry for the Logs, used them to try to troubleshoot.

Comment: Did you try to remove line recipeImage.setParseFile(image)?

Comment: Which line does the logcat lead you to?

Comment: The last logcat entry i get is Log.d("Recept", "time: " + time);. So the compiler stops before the TextView entries is complete. So the compiler doesn't even go to the recipeImage.setParseFile(image); line.

Edit: I just want to clarify: I don't get the line "The text was fine" in logcat.

Answer (score 0):

So I found the issue was

```
recipeTime.setText(time);
```

don't work because I'm trying to pass an int where it should be a string.
instead writing `recipeTime.setText(time + "");` works. :)

Answer (score 0):

Replace
String text = (String)object.get("Text");

to
String text = object.getString("Text");

I hope this will help you.